# Strange compiler behaviour

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, cross-compiling, uclibc

I'm trying to compile my project, which uses boost.
Main integer type for me is a `int32_t` and `int64_t` from `sys/types.h`.
If I compile project with host-system compiler (GCC 4.8.3, x86_64) process finished with success and binary file is correct work, but if I try to cross compile to ARM with external toolchain (GCC 4.3.5, armv5te) proccess interrupts on

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi
Configured with: /home/vijay/sdk/SDK6.1/04_Software/05_ToolChain/02_Source/buildroot-2010.11-r46561/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/configure --prefix=/opt/Mozart_Toolchain/arm-eabi-uclibc/usr --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --host=i686-pc-linux-gnu --target=arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-sysroot=/opt/Mozart_Toolchain/arm-eabi-uclibc --with-build-time-tools=/opt/Mozart_Toolchain/arm-eabi-uclibc/usr/arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi/bin --disable-__cxa_atexit --enable-target-optspace --with-gnu-ld --disable-libssp --disable-multilib --disable-tls --enable-shared --with-gmp=/home/vijay/sdk/SDK6.1/04_Software/05_ToolChain/02_Source/buildroot-2010.11-r46561/output/toolchain/gmp --with-mpfr=/home/vijay/sdk/SDK6.1/04_Software/05_ToolChain/02_Source/buildroot-2010.11-r46561/output/toolchain/mpfr --disable-nls --enable-threads --disable-decimal-float --with-float=soft --with-abi=aapcs-linux --with-arch=armv5te --with-tune=arm926ej-s --with-pkgversion='Buildroot 2010.11' --with-bugurl=http://bugs.buildroot.net/
    Thread model: posix
    gcc version 4.3.5 (Buildroot 2010.11) 
    arm-linux-g++ -c -O3 -g -lprotobuf -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lcrypto -lboost_random -lboost_program_options -lboost_filesystem -lboost_chrono -lesyslog -lesyslog2stderr  -L/home/dcow/Work/Libs/Release/libesyslog/ -L../../ROOT/lib/ -I./ -I../common/ -I../common/protobuf/ -I../export/ -I../../libESyslog/ -I../../ROOT/include/ -DLINUX_GCC  eventmanager.cpp -o eventmanager.o
    In file included from eventmanager.h:8,
                     from eventmanager.cpp:3:
    serversession.h:20: error: reference to 'int32_t' is ambiguous
    /opt/Mozart_Toolchain/arm-eabi-uclibc/usr/include/sys/types.h:197: error: candidates are: typedef int int32_t
    ../../ROOT/include/boost/cstdint.hpp:260: error:                 typedef int boost::int32_t
    serversession.h:20: error: reference to 'int32_t' is ambiguous
    /opt/Mozart_Toolchain/arm-eabi-uclibc/usr/include/sys/types.h:197: error: candidates are: typedef int int32_t
    ../../ROOT/include/boost/cstdint.hpp:260: error:                 typedef int boost::int32_t
    serversession.h:20: error: 'int32_t' does not name a type
    In file included from eventmanager.cpp:7:
    networkmanager.h:64: error: reference to 'int32_t' is ambiguous
    cc1plus: error: candidates are: #'tree_list' not supported by dump_decl#<declaration error>
    ../../ROOT/include/boost/cstdint.hpp:260: error:                 typedef int boost::int32_t
    networkmanager.h:64: error: reference to 'int32_t' is ambiguous
    cc1plus: error: candidates are: #'tree_list' not supported by dump_decl#<declaration error>
    ../../ROOT/include/boost/cstdint.hpp:260: error:                 typedef int boost::int32_t
    networkmanager.h:64: error: 'int32_t' does not name a type
    In file included from eventmanager.cpp:8:
    subscriptionsmanager.h:29: error: reference to 'int64_t' is ambiguous
    cc1plus: error: candidates are: #'tree_list' not supported by dump_decl#<declaration error>
    ../../ROOT/include/boost/cstdint.hpp:308: error:                 typedef boost::long_long_type boost::int64_t
    subscriptionsmanager.h:29: error: expected ',' or '...' before 'messageId'
    subscriptionsmanager.h:29: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'int64_t' with no type
    subscriptionsmanager.h:30: error: reference to 'int64_t' is ambiguous
    cc1plus: error: candidates are: #'tree_list' not supported by dump_decl#<declaration error>
    ../../ROOT/include/boost/cstdint.hpp:308: error:                 typedef boost::long_long_type boost::int64_t
    subscriptionsmanager.h:30: error: expected ',' or '...' before 'messageId'
    subscriptionsmanager.h:30: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'int64_t' with no type
    eventmanager.cpp: In member function 'bool rvi::EventManager::handleAuthorization(ObjectId&, NVRMessage&)':
    eventmanager.cpp:177: error: reference to 'int64_t' is ambiguous
    cc1plus: error: candidates are: #'tree_list' not supported by dump_decl#<declaration error>
    ../../ROOT/include/boost/cstdint.hpp:308: error:                 typedef boost::long_long_type boost::int64_t
    eventmanager.cpp:177: error: reference to 'int64_t' is ambiguous
    cc1plus: error: candidates are: #'tree_list' not supported by dump_decl#<declaration error>
    ../../ROOT/include/boost/cstdint.hpp:308: error:                 typedef boost::long_long_type boost::int64_t
    eventmanager.cpp:177: error: expected `;' before 'messageId'
    eventmanager.cpp:179: error: 'messageId' was not declared in this scope
    make: *** [eventmanager.o] Error 1
```

I'm NOT use `using namespace boost`

How I compile boost:

```
cd $(BOOST_SOURCES_DIR)
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=$(ROOT_DIR)
echo "using gcc : arm : arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi-g++ ;" > tools/build/v2/user-config.jam
./b2 toolset=gcc-arm link=shared --with-system --with-random --with-thread --with-signals --with-regex --with-filesystem --with-date_time --with-program_options --with-chrono -threading=multi  install
```

Comment: Why are both C and C++ tagged?

Comment: Did you install boost libraries for cross-compilation ?

Comment: @kviiri, is a lib, whith API is C only, but internal is C++

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch, yes, ofcourse

Comment: @Dcow: You're compiling as C++, so the question is a C++ question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost's `<boost/cstdint.hpp>` definitions are colliding with uclibc's sys/types.h.

This should not occur. You might have `using namespace boost;` in inappropriate places (in headers or before including library headers).

Comment: project is 100% clean for `using namespace boost`

Comment: or `using boost::int32_t` or something like that

Comment: ok, if I have it in project, why host compiler (yes, glibc, but is has int32_t in sys/types too!) succefully compile code ?

Comment: Because there's a difference in the system library headers?

Comment: ok, maybe, but I still absolutely sure, what my project is clean for that usings...
How I can diagnose that problem ?

Comment: You can inspect the pre-processed source (preprocess on the cross-compilation toolchain and look for the offending declarations)